# A password tester which alerts the user if spaces are present

Tags: javascript, html, loops, while-loop, passwords

A JavaScript program is required to request, via a dialogue box, a password
from a user. The input, which can be of any length, must be validated such
that it is only valid if it has no spaces. Any character, other than a space, is
permissible. As soon as a space is detected, the program should terminate
with a message provided in an alert box stating:
Invalid, contains a space!

Can anyone help me correct my code, this is my attempt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">

Password: <input type="password" name="password">
</form> ;


var i  ;
var validpassword = "" ;
var passworduser ; 
var isNoSpace =  (?!.*\\s) 



if(isNoSpace = false; i > charAt(i)) //
    alert("Password contains a space!")

    for(j = 1; j<=yourString.length; j++){

        validpassword += ’*’;

    }

    document.write("valid password")

else    
    document.write("password not valid")     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know that you need a `<script>` tag to run JavaScript right?

Comment: comparison in JavaScript is done using `==` or `===` for strict type check. `if ( isNoSpace == false ) { /* isNoSpace is equal to false */ }`

Comment: What is `isNoSpace` supposed to be? It looks kind of like a regexp, but there are no `//` delimiters around it. And you didn't use it to test the password.

Comment: You need to run your code inside the `onchange` handler for the input. Otherwise it will just run when the page is loaded, before the user has typed anything.

Comment: Spaces inside a password are perfectly valid and should not lead to an error message. As long as you store only the hash of a password, it cannot raise any problems in your code neither.

Answer (score 3):

```
var containingSpace = function(str) {
  return str.indexOf(' ') > -1;
}

console.log(containingSpace('abc')); // false
console.log(containingSpace('ab c')); // true
```

Comment: `<html>
<body>
<script type = "text/JavaScript">


<form action="">

Password: <input type="password" name="password">
</form> ;


var i  ;

var validpassword = "" ;

var passworduser ; 




var containingSpace = function(str) {
  return str.indexOf(' ') > -1;
}

console.log(containingSpace('abc')); // false
console.log(containingSpace('ab c')); // true 
 
 
 
for(j = 1; j<=yourString.length; j++){

validpassword += ’*’;

}

document.write("valid password")

else

document.write("password not valid") 








 
 
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: this is my updated code but still can't get it to work, also could someone tell me how to format it correctly?

Comment: @AndreasPoppmeier You need to understand what `console.log` is. As well   as https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try with `var isNoSpace = passworduser == passworduser.replace(" ", "");`.

It will check if the `passworduser` string is the same even when spaces are removed. If it is, it will return true (so `isNoSpace = true`).

The syntax I have used is equivalent to this

```
var isNoSpace;
if (passworduser == passworduser.replace(" ", "")) {
    isNoSpace = true;
else
    isNoSpace = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

**RegEx:** /\s+/

```
var pattern = /\s+/;

if (pattern.test(userString)) {
    document.write("password not valid");
} else {
    document.write("valid password");
}
```

Comment: \s is an extra work! It will also search for tabs too. @dev-null solution is perfectly straight forward.